# How to use "like" feature in facebook c# sdk 5.4.1?

Tags: c#, html, facebook, sdk, facebook-like

in facebook developers site it seems pretty easy.just make a HTTP POST to POST_ID/likes(i got the post i.d).
in c# sdk v.5.4.1 there is a POST method but i can't figure out how to use it and make the right call.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the face book API documentation..here http://developers.facebook.com/

```
            var fb = new FacebookClient("my token"); 
            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.message = "the publish msg"; 
            dynamic result = fb.Post("/me/feed", parameters); 
            var id = result.id; 
            var res = fb.Post("/" + id + "/likes");
```

Comment: the developers.facebook.com link cant help me in my case.i want to know how to use the post call using the c# sdk.

Comment: Could you post your code OR you can use javascript for such trivial task.

Comment: i want to do it using c# sdk. e.g var fb = new FacebookClient("token");                    fb.post("here i dont know what to write to make the right post reqest")

Comment: Surely it's just fb.post("1234567/likes") (where 1234567 is the post ID), no?

Comment: i tried this: fb.(id+"/likes"); and i get this :Unhandled Exception: Facebook.FacebookOAuthException: (OAuthException) (#100) Error finding the requested story
at Facebook.FacebookClient.Api(String path, IDictionary`2 parameters, HttpMethod httpMethod, Type resultType)
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.Post(String path, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.Post(Object parameters)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , FacebookClient , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid2[T0,T1](CallSite site,
 T0 arg0, T1 arg1)

Comment: this is my complete code:var fb = new FacebookClient("my token");
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.message = "the publish msg";                        dynamic result = fb.Post("me/feed", parameters);
var id = result.id;
var res = fb.Post(id+"/likes");

Comment: You have invalid access_token,  here is the class,  which explain you every thing. https://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk/blob/master/facebook/FacebookAPI.cs

Comment: i'm sure i have a valid token because it let me upload photos,links,new status ect. otherwise i couldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue so I tried few things & this worked for me

```
var token = "[your access token]";
var fb = new Facebook.FacebookClient(token);

var postId = "173213306032925_745288855492031"; //replace this with your big id which comprises of [userid]_[postid]

Console.WriteLine(fb.Post(id+"/likes", null).ToString());       // should print 'True'

Console.WriteLine(fb.Get("173213306032925_745288855492031/likes").ToString());    //should give you details
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        public void FacebookLike(AppConnect appconnect )
    {
        try
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> tokens = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            string fb_exchange = appconnect.UserToken;
            string url =
            string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token={3}&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&scope={1}&client_secret={2}",
            appconnect.AppID, appconnect.ExtendedPermissions, appconnect.AppSecret, fb_exchange);
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                string vals = reader.ReadToEnd();
                foreach (string token in vals.Split('&'))
                {
                    //meh.aspx?token1=steve&token2=jake&...
                    tokens.Add(token.Substring(0, token.IndexOf("=")),
                        token.Substring(token.IndexOf("=") + 1, token.Length - token.IndexOf("=") - 1));
                }
            }
            string access_token = tokens["access_token"];
            var client = new FacebookClient(access_token);
            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject(); parameters.idobject = "";

            client.Post("/" + appconnect.AppID.ToString() + "_" + appconnect.PostID.ToString() + "/Likes", parameters);
           // MessageBox.Show("....... Done ..........");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message +"\n"+ex.InnerException);
        }


    }
 class AppConnect
{
    //tring appId, string Appsecret, string userToken, string userID, string PostID

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public  string AppID { get; set; } = "991341734653453831";
    public  string AppSecret { get; set; } = "99dfbf29234ergec4a";
    public string UserID { get; set; } = null;
    public  string UserToken { get; set; } = null; 
    public  string PostID { get; set; } = null;
    public  string ExtendedPermissions { get; set; } = "user_posts, publish_actions, publish_pages,manage_pages,user_likes";
}
```